# How to add text item to a winform listbox that been already bound with a datasource

Tags: c#, .net, listbox, bind, listitem

I have c# `Winform` `Listbox` that is already been bound to a `data source`.

```
var custList=Cusomer.CustomerList();
lstbox.DataSource=custList;
`enter code here`
lstbox.DisplayMember="CustName";
lstbox.ValueMemebr="CustId";
```

Now I want to add a text called "All" to the same `list box` so that it should be displayed as the first `listitem`. Also the list items added through `binding` should also be present there. My idea is when the user selects the "ALL" option all of the list items has to be selected automatically.

Any idea how I can add the new text value?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hope this will help you.

```
    void InitLstBox()
    {
        //Use a generic list instead of "var"
        List<Customer> custList = new List<Customer>(Cusomer.CustomerList());
        lstbox.DisplayMember = "CustName";
        lstbox.ValueMember = "CustId";
        //Create manually a new customer
        Customer customer= new Customer();
        customer.CustId= -1;
        customer.CustName= "ALL";
        //Insert the customer into the list
        custList.Insert(0, contact);

        //Bound the listbox to the list
        lstbox.DataSource = custList;

        //Change the listbox's SelectionMode to allow multi-selection
        lstbox.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.MultiExtended;
        //Initially, clear slection
        lstbox.ClearSelected();
    }
```

And if you want to select all customer when the user select ALL, add this method:

```
    private void lstbox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //If ALL is selected then select all other items
        if (lstbox.SelectedIndices.Contains(0))
        {
            lstbox.ClearSelected();
            for (int i = lstbox.Items.Count-1 ; i > 0 ; i--)
                lstbox.SetSelected(i,true);
        }
    }
```

Off course, don't forget to set the event handler :)

```
 this.lstbox.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.lstbox_SelectedIndexChanged);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `ListBox.Items.Insert` and specify `0` as the index.

```
ListBox1.Items.Insert(0, "All");
```